# Django - Custom User Model Signal Issue: Token Creation Occurs Before User Is Persisted to Database

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, authorization, token

CustomUser extends User from django.contrib.auth.models

```
class CustomUser(User):
    user_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    has_mod_rights = models.BooleanField()
    picture = models.BinaryField(null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    is_premium = models.BooleanField()
    unban_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

and my signal should be triggered when new CustomUser is created

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=CustomUser)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created and instance.pk:
        token = Token.objects.create(user=instance)
```

the registration view:

```
@api_view(['POST', ])

def registration_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = RegistrationSerializer(data=request.data)
        data = {}
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.save()
            # breakpoint()
            data['response'] = 'successfully registered a new user'
            data['email'] = user.email
            data['username'] = user.username
            token = Token.objects.get(user=user).key
            data['token']=token
        else: 
            data: serializer.errors
        return Response(data)
```

and serializer:

```
class RegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    password2 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
fields = ['username', 'password', 'password2', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name']


    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = CustomUser(
            email=self.validated_data['email'],
            username=self.validated_data['username'],
            has_mod_rights=False,
            is_premium=False,
        )
        password = self.validated_data['password']
        password2= self.validated_data['password2']
        
        if password != password2:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'password': 'Password must match!'})
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user
```

and i get

FAILED authorisation/tests/test_auth.py::test_registration - ValueError: Model instances passed to related filters must be saved.

Error when running

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_registration():
    client = APIClient()

    # Prepare data for a valid registration
    valid_data = valid_login_data()[0]

    url = '/api/auth/register'
    response = client.post(url, valid_data)


    assert response.status_code == 200, response.json()
    assert CustomUser.objects.filter(email="test@example.com").count() == 1
```

At the moment of

`token = Token.objects.get(user=user).key`

in view the Token table is empty
but signal is toggled (idk when) and it creates token and by then the new created  user is not in the user table, so could it be because of some desynchronization

Registration without token authorisation was working fine

saving token after creation - no results`your text`
making sure use is checked

`transaction.on_commit(lambda: Token.objects.create(user=instance))`

doesnt helps